# How to remove element from multidimensional array in JavaScript (angular 5)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have structure like this:

```
    [{
    "id": 150,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 72,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 73,
            "children": [],
          },
          {
            "id": 77,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 146,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "id": 147,
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "id": 148,
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "id": 149,
                            "children": []
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

and now need to delete element with id 149
need to use filter with recursion or what i don't know = (
**condition one - nesting can be unlimited**

Comment: If you are using this to generate HTML, you can use `*ngIf` and compare the ID there.

Comment: why on earth is your data structured like that?

Comment: and what did you try until now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach for `children` and check if the actual object's `id` is equal to the wanted `id`. Then splice the array and return `true` to stop further iteration (assuming all `id` are unique).

```js
var data = [{ id: 150, children: [{ id: 72, children: [{ id: 73, children: [] }, { id: 77, children: [{ id: 146, children: [{ id: 147, children: [{ id: 148, children: [{ id: 149, children: [] }] }] }] }] }] }] }],
    id = 149;

data.some(function iter (o, i, a) {
    if (o.id === id) {
        a.splice(i, 1);
        return true;
    }
    return o.children && o.children.some(iter);
});
    
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Managing data of that structure is unrealistic. You could get to that element with id of 149 but it would be slow and cumbersome.

I would suggest re-structuring your array to not have so much nesting.